# "No result found" JqueryUI category listing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The problem I am facing here is http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories I am unable to figure out how to make "No result found" appear in the drop down list of auto complete menu search. Can someone share there insight on how this can be achieved?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Categories</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  .ui-autocomplete-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .2em .4em;
    margin: .8em 0 .2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
          ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        that._renderItemData( ul, item );
      });
    }
  });
  </script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var data = [
      { label: "anders", category: "" },
      { label: "andreas", category: "" },
      { label: "antal", category: "" },
      { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
      { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
      { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
      { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
      { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
      { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
    ];

    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: data
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the not found text? Another field? In the autocomplete menu? Others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
     delay: 0,
     source: data
  });
```

Replace To:

```
  $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: function(request, response) {
         var result = data.slice(0);
         result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(result, request.term);

        if(! result.length) {
            result.push({
              label: 'No Result Found',
              category: "",
              isPlaceholder: true
            });
        }
       response(result);
     }
  });
```

See [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fSH8K7x4MYsF7c30pO4g?p=preview)

Comment: @DanielEuchar Its my pleasure.